# IIS and ASP.NET is locking my PInvoke dll

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, pinvoke

I have an ASP.NET MVC website that uses an internal dll for some PInvoke stuff. The dll is located in the /bin folder next to the other assemblies. This works well, but if I want to replace the content of the /bin folder with the newest set of files by copying onto the existing files (this is on a test server) the PInvoke dll is locked/used by the w3wp.exe worker process and cannot be replaced except after you recycle the apppool or restart IIS.

Is this standard behavior or can I somehow instruct the ASP.NET runtime to take a shadow copy of the PInvoke dll similar to the regular assemblies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, if the IIS has an handle of the DLL, you won't be able to replace the DLL.

You mentioned APPPool Recycle, and IIS Restart...

I guess you may not have used touching your web.config file. I mean, open your web.config in notepad, make a change [like add a space and remove it] and save the file. This will recycle your application domain and hence the assembly reference should ideally be released [unless it is a shared assembly].

Comment: I am aware of the recycling when editing web.config, I was just rather surprised that the I could not copy-replace the PInvoke dll similarly to the regular .NET assemblies and was looking for a some more indepth knowledge on how to possibly instruct IIS/w3wp to not have a hard handle on the file.